# The Positioning is off on Click Here Button When Browser is Not Full Screen

Tags: html, css

The Video Sign looks good when browser is full size on my monitor but If I make the browser just a little bit smaller it starts to look off right away and starts to cover "photo Booth". I just want make sure the code is setup correctly for the video button sign before I start adding media  queries. (mobile not setup yet)

http://photoboothtemplates360.com/

```
header .video-sign {     
  position: absolute;     
  bottom: -30px;     
  right: 28rem; 
}
```

[Screenshot of Website Look at "click For Video" Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XO25.jpg)

Comment: What you mean when you say that *the video sign starts to look off*. How do you want it to look? Right now is doing what is supposed to do, based on your css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video sign to stay closer to the right side of the parent, you could change your css to use pixels.

```
header .video-sign {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

If you wanted it to be more flexible, you could use percentages.

```
header .video-sign {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 5%;
}
```

If you wanted it to stay as close as possible to the right side, the `video-sign` div has enough padding that it would look good even with `right: 0`.

But is hard to tell without knowing exactly how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks basically what I dont want the sign to do is cover up "photo Booth" the image behind it when the browser gets smaller. I want make sure the website looks good on laptops and smaller monitors.

Comment: @ruben005 then either of the three options above should work for you, all of them make the sign stay close to the right edge of the parent div. Try them out and see which one behaves in a way that you like better. If it solves your problem please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted afterwards.